# c++ templates how to call a template from one file that needs access to template of another file

Tags: c++, templates

I am new to template and as an exercise , I am trying to write my own template iterator in one file and later on use that iterator in find algorithm in another file.

e.g. in myfind.h I have

```
#ifndef my_find_header
#define  my_find_header

template <typename T, typename TIter>
inline
TIter * find (TIter * start , TIter * stop ,  const T & value)  
{     
    while ((start != stop ) && (*start != value))
    {
        start++;
    }
    return start;
}
#endif
```

In arr_it.h I have

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef arr_it_header 
#define arr_it_header 

template <typename T>
class arr_it
{
  public:
    arr_it(T *p);

    T & operator * () const;
    arr_it operator++ (int);
    bool operator != (const arr_it<T> & other) const;
  private:
    T * my_p;
};


//start of definitions
template <typename T>
inline
arr_it<T>:: arr_it(T *p)       
{
    my_p = p;
}


template <typename T>
inline
T & arr_it<T>::operator * () const 
{        
    return *my_p;                
}
template <typename T>
inline
arr_it<T> arr_it<T>::operator++ (int)
{
    arr_it<T> result(*this);
    my_p++;
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
inline
bool arr_it<T>::operator != (const arr_it<T> &     other)             const
    {
        return (my_p != other.my_p);
    }

    #endif
```

and I call this in my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "builtin_arr_it.h"
#include "myfind.h"


int main()
{
    int my_array[10];
    for (int i =0; i<100; i++)
    {
        my_array[i]=1;
    }

my_array[47]= -1; 
    my_array[4]= -1;   
    const int value(-1);

    arr_it <int> start (my_array);
    arr_it <int> stop  (my_array +10);


    arr_it<int> p = (find (start, stop, value)); 
return 0;
}
```

However , I get the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(array_it<int>&, array_it<int>&, const     int&)'
```

while compiling with g++ ;

So my question is, how do I include the files(or something along those lines),
that would allow template of one file to access/recognize template of another file.

By the way, I am not sure whether the title correctly captures the issue. Feel free to change the name of the title

Thanks.

Comment: Don you mean `*start != value` in `find`?

Comment: `#include <stdlib.h>` Although I don't see where you need it, if it's required you should use the corresponding C++ header `<cstdlib>` instead.

Comment: You should initialize your whole array, not only the element you want to find. Else, reading from it results in Undefined Behaviour. Try `int my_array[10] = {0};`, for instance.

Comment: @DyP the code has more elements to it. I only included the lowest granular stuff that reproduces my issues. I needed the stdlib for something else I am doing. You are right about `start != value` part, I fixed that. I also initialized the array elements. But the issue remains that I get an error about compiler not being able to deduce the find function ...

Comment: It's clear that those changes don't solve your problem, otherwise I would have posted them as an answer, not just as comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing references to your `find` function, but it is defined with pointers to the iterators. Change the definition

```
TIter& find (TIter& start , TIter& stop ,  const T & value)
```

And don't dereference the iterators in the body.

Comment: @thassan This is *not* the correct solution as you are modifying `start` in the algorithm. In `main`, do you really expect `start` to be modified after you called `find()`?

Comment: Also, it doesn't work with rvalues, such as from a hypothetical `begin` function.

Comment: Feel free to edit to improve this answer, I admit to being inexperienced with C++11 rvalues. My own practice would be to use `const TIter&`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a few superfluous pointers, try

```
template <typename T, typename TIter>
inline
TIter find (TIter start , TIter stop ,  const T & value)
{
    // ...
}
```

as the signature for your function. (note the missing `*`s)

Also, as DyP noted, you probably want `*start != value` instead of `*start == value`.